# Is this Proof correct? Given $A$, $B$ and $C$, prove $\exists P\space\forall x\space(x\in P \iff x=A \space\vee x=B \space\vee x=C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

My attempt goes as follows:

$\exists \space A, B, C$

Axiom of Pair:
$$\exists D \space \forall X \space (X\in D\Longleftrightarrow X=A \space \vee X =B ) \space\wedge \exists G \space \forall X \space (X\in G\Longleftrightarrow X=C )  $$

Axiom of Pair:
$$\exists F \space \forall X \space (X \in F \iff X = D \space\vee X = G)$$

Axiom of Union:
$$\exists (\cup F) \space \forall X(X \in \cup F \iff X =A \space \vee X =B \space \vee X=C)$$

$\therefore$ there exists a set $\cup F$ which is denoted by $P$, which only admissible elements are $A$, $B$ or $C$.

Another question of mine is about defining $P$ using the Axiom of Comprenhension, for which:

$$P = \left\{ X \in \cup F \space| \space X =A \space \vee X =B \space \vee X = C\right\}$$

Could this also be a correct way to define such set?

Comment: Your pretty much there, but the axiom of union is different than what you have stated. Rather, what you have is implied by the axiom of union applied to the stes $D$ and $G$.

Comment: You could also define such a $P$ with comprehension. You just need to find one set that has all $A$, $B$, and $C$ as members

Comment: @IsAdisplayName But is not $F$, a set which only contains the elements $D$ or $G$ (or both)? Wouldn't the axiom of union be necessary for establishing the existence of a set $P$ which contains the elements of the elements of $F$ which can be $A$, $B$ or $C$.